# Visual Studio Code Task to Compile and Run .c Files

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, task

How can I create a task in Visual Studio Code (the most recent version) to compile and run .c files.
I found this online:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile and run C",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "(gcc -g ${file} -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension}) -and (./${fileBasenameNoExtension})",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I managed to tweak it but it still wont compile and run at the same time, instead I get this:

```
> Executing task: (gcc -g d:\ISEP\ARQCP\partilha\arqcp19202deg01\pl0_7.c -o pl0_7) -and (./pl0_7) <

False

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Is there any way to compile and run my code with a simple shortcut (currently i press CTRL+SHIFT+B to "compile and run")?

Comment: is `gcc` in the path?

Comment: Yes gcc is in that specific path "C:\MinGW\bin".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept looking for a way to do it and I found this simple extension: [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Basically it just adds a *Run Code* button for most of the coding languages and it makes it so much easier.